# Index table beside plot

Tags: r, graph, plot, data.table

I am looking for a way to add a table beside a plot (outside of the actual Cartesian canvas). The table would be an index of sort with more information correlating to the labels already on the plot. I have a scatter plot as follows created using ggplot:

[image]

The R code for the plot is as follows:

```
png("image.png", width = 2000, height = 1500, res = 85);
ggplotXY <- ggplot(scatterPlotData, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=labels, label=labels)) +
geom_point() +
geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=0)
ggplotXY
dev.off()
```

I have a column in my data frame that has the name of the point. So, for example, something long these lines:

```
1: Name One
2: Name Two
3: Name Three
.
.
.
150: Name 150
```

How would I go about adding such a table? I don't want to add the whole name in the scatter plot as it would overlap a lot of points. As you can see, even the numbers themselves overlap although it's acceptable.

An inputs are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this for a minimal example:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
grid.arrange(qplot(1,1), legend = tableGrob(matrix(1:10, ncol=2)))
```